# How to send request to remote laravel web app

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to send request from raspberry pi using GuzzleHttp to laravel project

i tried

my script :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://mydomain.fake/api/print-invoice');
echo $res->getBody();
```

my routes and controller at the laravel project

```
 Route::get('/print-invoice','AutoPrintController@autoPrint');
```

```
{
    public function autoPrint(){
        $response = 'test request';
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

i got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error:
 `GET http://mydomain.fake/api/print-invoice` resulted in a `404 Not Found` 
response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> 
<title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found (truncated...) in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception
/RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script
/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(66): GuzzleHttp\Exception
\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp
\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script

/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise
\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises
/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\ in /opt/lampp/htdocs/print-script
/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113
```

i also tried

`curl http://mydomain.fake/api/print-invoice`

from terminal

and got

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>302 Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Found</h1>
        <p>The document has moved <a href="http://mydomain.fake/api/print-invoice">here</a>.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at mydomain.fake Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update : problem was wrong path ..

Comment: As you can see that Guzzle say the page is not found. Did you create a virtual host?

Comment: Did you write that route in web.php? If so, it will not work. cause when you are using http://server_name/api/your_parameter it will not work. You are already called api.php file for route. Maybe thats why you are not getting it?

Comment: I wrote the route first in web.php and use the url without /api/ and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `php artisan serve` is on and in request used json_decode

echo json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());

Comment: `json_decode` isn't gonna do anything for that 404 page response.

Comment: Yes It is a response part that will apply when the data will come from server

Comment: i'm testing on live test server